# image of elevatezoom not scrolling in Cell Phone

Tags: jquery, mobile, scroll, mobile-phones

image of elevatezoom  not scrolling in Cell Phone

When there is a picture of elevatezoom pluging And you want the Scroll
And you stand on the image with your finger
Can not Scroll Up or Down in mobile phones

need help

Comment: Hello,I have the same issue did you manage to find a solution ?

Comment: please refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40128811/scrolling-not-working-in-mobile-on-image-of-elevatezoom-js-data-zoom-image

Answer (score 3):

I was looking to destroy elevateZoom on mobile for a better user experience and was running into the same issue.  I couldn't scroll the webpage when I tried over the image.  I found that the `touchmove` event is prevented from normal function via the following code:

```
b.$elem.bind("touchmove", function(a) {
            a.preventDefault();
            b.setPosition(a.originalEvent.touches[0] || a.originalEvent.changedTouches[0])
        });
```

I removed elevateZoom and un-binded `touchmove` with the following code.

```
        $('#imgzoom').removeData('elevateZoom');
        $('.zoomWrapper img.zoomed').unwrap();
        $('.zoomContainer').remove();
        $("#imgzoom").unbind("touchmove");
```

Answer (score -1):

This works in elevateZoom 3.0.8:

In elevatezoom.js, search for "touchmove" and "touchend" and remove or comment all binds that use these words. Now you can scroll on mobile devices (using touch), and the lens still works on desktop.