# scrolling not working in mobile on image of elevatezoom.js data-zoom-image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used following code for zoom images in product details page but on when image of zoom pluging you want to scroll and you stand on the image with your finger can not scroll Up or Down in mobile phones

```
<div class="relative d_inline_b m_bottom_10 qv_preview d_xs_block" style="height: 440px">
     <img title="Silver Diamond Band Ring" itemprop="image" style="cursor:zoom-in;position: relative;top: 50%;transform: translateY(-50%);" id="zoom_image" src="/img/product/thumb/1510161025300784.jpg" data-zoom-image="/img/product/big/1510161025299740.jpg" class="tr_all_hover" alt="Silver Diamond Band Ring">
     <a href="/images/preview_zoom_1.jpg" class="d_block button_type_5 r_corners tr_all_hover box_s_none color_light p_hr_0"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Issue solved by doing this :**

Search for `touchmove` event in `jquery.elevatezoom.js` and remove `preventDeafult()` from mobile view.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same problem, and your answer was very helpful, but by removing preventDefault() the functionality of elevatezoom is removed from the desktop view.

I would remove only for mobile using javascript mediamatch:

```
                if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 640px)").matches) {
                /* The viewport is less than, or equal to, 640 pixels wide */
                } else {
                /* The viewport is greater than 640 pixels wide */
                e.preventDefault();
                }
```

To make the above change goto your elevatezoom.js and find 'e.preventDefault();' and replace with the above code.  Change max-width: 640px to your desired view port.

Hope that helps someone